# Swap X and Y axis table - bar char

Tags: microsoft-word, charts, microsoft-word-2013

I want to create a chart that has on X axis the complexity and in the Y axis the time with Microsoft Word 2013. Then, in the same chart I have to put the time and the complexity of two different tests.

[image]

Column A contains the complexity and columns B and C contain the time of the two tests. The problem is that in this way I have on X axis the time and on Y axis the complexity, like in this way:

[image]

How do I put the Complexity on X axis and the time on Y axis?

Note, I have already raised a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1029163/swap-x-and-y-axis-table) but, with scatter plot, when I edit a column I do swap the value of X and Y series (as shown in the link). With bar char, word only shows the value of a serie (and not values of X and Y), so it not possible to swap X and Y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the chart type from bar chart to column chart.

The x-axis will run from 0 to 10000 (left to right) by default.  However, if you want to have your data displayed from 10000 to 0 left to right, format the x-axis and in the Axis Options tick the box "Categories in reverse order".